# how to embed another timestamp but not now to mongoid

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I have activities that I should add to mongodb, activities have, dates and times, I should sort them, What I want, is not to have another field for timestamp and index that field also, I don't want the time when the document is created, I want to embed that activitie's timestamp to mongoid, I searched and tried this one but did not work,

```
"_id" => new MongoId($stamp)
```

Is there a chance, that I can embed future timestamp to mongoid ? thank you :)

Comment: Yes this is possible but it depends on what driver you are using, i.e. the PHP driver doesn't actually allow this without making your own function. What driver are you using?

Comment: I am using php driver, how can I write a function for my purpose ? which functions should I add ?

Comment: Here is an example of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370143/create-mongodb-objectid-from-date-in-the-past-using-php-driver/14380093#14380093

Comment: I guess I searched for wrong query :) I will try this function thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not directly through the driver. I have written an example at [Create MongoDB ObjectID from date in the past using PHP driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370143/create-mongodb-objectid-from-date-in-the-past-using-php-driver/14380093#14380093) that shows you how to do this.