# Generating Mongo ObjectId (_id) with custom time?

Tags: mongodb, objectid

I am porting over a table of articles from MySQL to Mongo DB. I understand that the _id field generated by Mongo has the time of creation somehow in there and can be extracted or you can query against it. Because of this, I want to use it to have my created_time INT timestamp from MySQL. Is there a way when moving my data to generate an _id for Mongo that will have the time  stamp that I currently have for my records in a separate field?

Comment: You might find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125521/uses-for-mongodb-objectid-creation-time discussion helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. In the C# driver for instance, there's a constructor for `ObjectId` where you can pass in a timestamp, see [this source file](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/MongoDB.Bson/ObjectModel/ObjectId.cs). It's easiest to use the helper method `GenerateNewId`:

```
var id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01));
```

I don't know which programming language you're using and whether the driver in that language supports this feature, but I guess this is widely available.

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370143/create-mongodb-objectid-from-date-in-the-past-using-php-driver) contains the code for Java, mongoose and python, and the answer contains code for PHP. "Widely available" seems to be a wrong assumption, it's not yet implemented in the PHP driver, for instance.

Comment: Hah, I'm actually using PHP. Not surprised of it's limits but I didn't think that would matter. Is there a way to generate the MongoId using the new DateTime() object by sending a raw query to Mongo instead of using the driver to do it or an alternative approach for PHP users?

Comment: The referenced source file has moved. As of today it is at: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/ObjectModel/ObjectId.cs